# Existence of an inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with continuous derivative. Prove the existence of $>0$ such that for all $x, y\in[a, b]$ the inequality |()−()|≤ |−| is true.

I was thinking of proving this using the Mean Value Theorem but I am not really sure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate question found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cf(x)-f(y)%7C%20%5Cle%20M%7Cx-y%7C%20%24%2C%20derivative%20continuous)

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is continuous on the compact set $[a,b]$ and hence bounded by some M.  Now use MVT

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$ f $ is continuous and differentiable at $ [a,b] \implies$

$$(\forall x,y\in[a,b])\;(\exists c\in(x,y))\;:$$
$$\; f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)f'(c)$$

but $ f' $ is continuous at the compact $ [a,b] $
$$\implies f' \text{ is bounded}$$

$$\implies (\exists M>0)\;:$$
$$\;(\forall t\in [a,b])\;|f'(t)|\le M$$

Comment: The question is a duplicate.

Comment: How can i know it ?

Comment: In fact the question was already closed when you posted your answer. As a >4yr member with >50K reputation you should also know how to search for obvious duplicates.